# Force responsive Paypal layout

Tags: layout, paypal

I'm using Paypal as a vendor. 
My website is responsive and somehow I'd like to use the new Paypal responsive layout for my customers as well when it comes to payment.

Is there any kind of parameter I can submit in the buy now Paypal URLs so that I force the new responsive paypal layout? It seems as if there's still an A/B test ongoing on Paypal side - old none responsive layout vs. the new one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I found out is if your API call contains either item details or recurring payment, it uses old layout, otherwise it uses new layout.